# Is there any any UNIX/Linux command which can check if 2 lines are continuous

Tags: linux, bash, unix, text, awk

For e.g. Consider a file sentences.txt

```
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence Y
```

We see that first `This is sentence X` comes that `This is sentence Y`.
Is there any command to check if 2 line are continuous like 
`This is sentence X` followed by `This is sentence X` or
`This is sentence Y` followed by `This is sentence Y`. In line 11 and 12 , we see that 2 line are repeated.

Comment: Use some tiny [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) script

Answer (score 4):

You do not even need to use `awk` for this! 
You can simply use `uniq` command.

```
$ cat sentences.txt
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence Y

uniq -d sentences.txt
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
```

**Explanations:**

uniq is a very handy command that can print successive duplicates in a file, count them etc. Here I use the option `-d` to just print the duplicate successive lines.

**Bonus:**

If you want to add at which line you find the duplicates then you can use the following commands:

```
$ cat -n sentences.txt
     1  This is sentence Y
     2  This is sentence X
     3  This is sentence Y
     4  This is sentence X
     5  This is sentence Y
     6  This is sentence X
     7  This is sentence Y
     8  This is sentence X
     9  This is sentence X
    10  This is sentence Y
    11  This is sentence Y
$ cat -n sentences.txt | uniq -f1 -d
     8  This is sentence X
    10  This is sentence Y
```

Where `-f1` is used to ignore the first field (the lines numbering)

Last but not least, if you want to print all duplicates use `-D` option.

```
$ cat -n sentences.txt | uniq -f1 -D
     8  This is sentence X
     9  This is sentence X
    10  This is sentence Y
    11  This is sentence Y
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'p==$0{print NR, $0} {p=$0}' file
```

will print duplicate lines with line numbers

```
12 This is sentence X
14 This is sentence Y
```

if you don't need the line numbers

```
$ awk 'p==$0; {p=$0}' file
```

is enough.

Another alternative to grab attention

```
$ awk 'p==$0{printf "%s", "==DUP==> "} 1; {p=$0}'


This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence X
==DUP==> This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
==DUP==> This is sentence Y
```